# Use Javascript JSON output in External API

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I tried to use JSON output in an external API. When I tested the URL in Postman it did not show the JSON. What am I doing wrong?

**This is my test script:**

```
<div id="test"></div>

    var obj = new Object();
   obj.name = "Raj";
   obj.age  = 32;
   obj.married = false;
   var jsonString= JSON.stringify(obj);

   console.log(jsonString);
   var str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2); // spacing level = 2

   document.getElementById("test").innerText = str;
```

This is my output from Postman:

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that your javascript is evaluated in the browser, not on the server? Postman is not a browser with a js engine, so it just fetched the document from the server without doing anything with your javascript.

Comment: Are you trying to build an API yourself? It's unclear. It's a strange way to do so, and it won't work. As MikNiller says, JavaScript can only be executed in a browser. If you want to build an API which returns JSON, and can be called from any HTTP client program, not just a browser, then your API needs to have some code which is executed on the server, and which returns the JSON data directly, instead of returning some HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Its middleware that i used for a other application. I try it now in PHP using cURL but it ask for aa cookie. "API using the XMLHttpRequest, the withCredentials property must be set to true in order for the HTTP cookie to be sent with these requests."

Comment: cURL does not use XMLHttpRequest, so it's unclear why you'd get that error, or how. But you seem to have missed the point...the output of your API is intended for use in a browser only...it will not work if you use another type of client (such as PostMan or cURL)...you need to amend the API code to output raw JSON text, not HTML+JS.